# Is it possible to add a link in the image that shows up in slimbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, href, slimbox

I have an image gallery and I'm using slimbox in it. I want to know if it's possible to add a link in the image that shows up after clicking/hovering an image in the gallery, because I was able to add a link in the title/caption.

```
<a rel='slimbox' href="images/img2.jpg" title="&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot; &gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;">
   <img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/img1.jpg" width="128" height="164" alt=""  />
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'possible to add a link in the image'? The link as text, or something that you can click to go to that link?

Comment: What I want is that when I click 'img2.jpg' I'll be redirected to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can add the title/caption to each image. But you can not add a link to image directly. Try to add link in caption as in [Slimbox demo](http://www.digitalia.be/demo/slimbox/). Please check the source. You can get some idea to customize.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    window.addEvent("domready", function() {
        if (!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            $$("a[href^=http://www.flickr.com/photos/] > img:first-child[src]").getParent().slimbox({
                loop: true,
                initialWidth: 1024,
                initialHeight: 768,
                overlayOpacity: 0.6,
                overlayFadeDuration: 200,
                resizeDuration: 1000,
                resizeTransition: Fx.Transitions.Elastic.easeOut,
                counterText: "This is image <strong>{x}</strong> on a total of <strong>{y}</strong> in this fabulous Flickr image gallery",
                previousKeys: [37, 80, 16],
                nextKeys: [39, 78, 17],
            }, function(el) {
                return [el.firstChild.src.replace(/_[mts]\.(\w+)$/, ".$1"),
                    (el.title || el.firstChild.alt) + '<br />Visit the <a href="' + el.href + '">Flickr page</a> for this picture.'];
            });
        }
        try {
            _gat._getTracker("UA-760577-1")._trackPageview();
        } catch(e) {}
    });
//]]></script>

<h2>Customization</h2>

    <p>You can change every parameter of Slimbox and make it work with any kind of link or element.<br />

    Below is an example of integration with Flickr links and custom options.</p>

    <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/14516334@N00/345009210/"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/159/345009210_1f826cd5a1_t.jpg" alt="A nice bee." /></a><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/alphageek/233472093/" title="Keyboard navigation is also customized here so you can use the Shift and Ctrl keys to navigate between images. Also, navigating to the next image will bring you back to the first one (loop option)."><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/85/233472093_1f1d235e7b_t.jpg" alt="Flowers" /></a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post but as I mentioned earlier, I already added a link the caption what I'm trying to figure is adding a link on the image.